# Mid-print issue, extruder issue?

Tags: creality-ender-3, creality-ender-5, prusaslicer, creality

I have succumbed to asking the community for assistance. I've been scratching my head and lost many late nights and time trying to figure out what is going on with my 3D printer.

Please see the image of what's going on with it.

Sometimes my printer doesn't even get this far, most of the time it fails at the 5th layer or so because it stops extruding is what I suspect.

I've replaced the hot end entirely, a new thermistor inside the hot end, replaced the PTFE tube, upgraded the extruder feeder to aluminum. Replaced the extruder gear, and for some reason, the filament just stops feeding.

I've tried several retraction settings from 80 mm/s and 2 mm of filament, to 20 mm/s and 6 mm of filament.

Initial Layer Height: 0.25 mm

[image: Failed print]

I hope the community can help me out here.

Comment: Would you attach a drawing image of what the print is supposed to look like.  That doesn't look like the printer stopped extruding.  It looks like part of the print lifted off the print surface.  What material are you printing?

Comment: This looks like (multiple) layer shifting where finally the lower parts got bumped off. There could we'll be multiple problems at play here...

Comment: I am trying to print this headphone stand: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2446648 and using PLA. Not sure if its shifting but there's some empty spots as if the filament isn't being pushed through the nozzle. But I've replaced the nozzle, entire hotend, and tried various temps from 185 - 220. I've re-installed the PTFE tube over a dozen times, and replaced it with a new one.

Comment: This looks like what I get with defective models at times...

Comment: So I fixed one issue, my cooling fan for the hot end wasn't spinning properly due to stringing, the strings of filament wrapped inside the motor. So now that I replaced it, the PLA doesn't seem to expand and get stuck in the hot end as much. However, it still is happening causing the PLA to expand in the PTFE tube causing a jam at time.

Answer (score 1):

Do the two loose pieces go where the fill shows up on the larger piece?  If so, you may have internal surfaces there that need deleting in your drawing so that they don't mess up your slice program.  Otherwise, the slice program may leave a gap in the gcode where you have no extrusion.

If you retract too much, it can cause the filament to jam in the hotend, but you wouldn't be getting all the mid-air extrusion, not connecting to anything.

We need more information to give you a more precise answer.  I suspect you have a settings or gcode/drawing issue rather than a hardware issue.

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to print this: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2446648 and I suspect may be its a slicer issue but I went back to an old print and it does the same issue now where after 5 layers it just leaves blobs on the print.